# search bar in toolbar in SwiftUI Xcode 12 for macOS App

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, uisearchbar, xcode12

In the newest iteration of Xcode (12) there is now a toolbar per default at the top of an App.

I like the design but I did not really understand how to use it yet. It seems to work differently than normal views.
[image]
Right now I want to add a search bar to it that covers in a adaptive layout all the space it can. But this does not seem to work. At least not like in a normal `View`. (I have to add that I am not the most experienced yet when it comes to SwiftUI).

This is how my search bar looks right now (tiny blue thing on the right next to the `Button`s that only expands when I type in it):

And this is the respective code of the toolbar in my main `View`:

```swift
var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                if !installedOnly || item.installed {
                    Text("\(item.name!)")
                        .foregroundColor(item.installed && !installedOnly ? .green : .white)
                }
            }
            .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
        }
        .toolbar {
            HStack{
                TextField("", text: $search_term)
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, maxHeight: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.infinity/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                Button(action: togglePinned) {
                    Label("Add Item", systemImage: installedOnly ? "pin.fill" : "pin")
                }
                Button(action: getApps) {
                    Label("Add Item", systemImage: "arrow.clockwise")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Any feedback is much appreciated!

Comment: I can not get this to work either. The TextField never stretches nor shrinks whatever one puts in the .frame()

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a HStack for the toolbar content. Every view in the toolbar is a item.

```
.toolbar {
     TextField("", text: $search_term)
         .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
         .frame(minWidth: 200)
     Button(action: togglePinned) {
         Label("Add Item", systemImage: installedOnly ? "pin.fill" : "pin")
     }
     Button(action: getApps) {
         Label("Add Item", systemImage: "arrow.clockwise")
     }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how this would work for a menubar app? I've tried this code but it fails to render the search bar in the menu bar infrastructure.